# Bitfield element when read giving a different value in C

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

My tiny snippet when trying to write a bitfield and reading back gives a different value

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
  int a:1;
  int b:1;
  int c:1;
  int d:5;
}node_t;

int main()
{
  node_t var;
  var.a = 1;
  var.b = 0;
  int a = var.a;
  int b = var.b;
  printf(" %d", a);
  printf(" %d", b);
 return 0;
}
```

This gives an output:

```
 -1 0
```

How my bitfield var.a becomes -1 instead of 1?

Comment: Read about how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) work for representing negative numbers, and remember that for signed types C will do *sign extension* of values.

Comment: The conversion of `int a : 1;` seems to do a sign extension. (I just try to imagine a 1 bit signed...) Hence, a simple conversion trick may fix: `int a = var.a != 0;` provides the intended ` 1 0`. [Live Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zuGICCpYVEpBAWHv)

Comment: Even simpler way to prevent sign extension: use `unsigned`. [Live Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2is3CbGw1CtEclU1)

Comment: So, after thinking a while I came to the conclusion that `unsigned : 1` is capable to store `0` or `1` but `int : 1` is capable to store `0` or `-1`. (I never saw it this way... ...but somehow it makes sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that `int` is signed by default. Hence, when you set one bit for the integer value, you will set the sign bit of that variable to `1`. Hence it would be a negative value. To that end, it would be two's complement techniques.